# JAX-WS Client on WAS 6.1

Tags: client, websphere, jax-ws, java-5

I have an application deployed on WAS 6.1 (without future pack). This application contains a JAX-WS client for a JAX-WS Web Service. Is this architecture possible? Considering that WAS 6.1 uses JAVA 1.5?
I encountered a lot of problems...like missing jars, and incompatible java version.
Can anyone say to me which are the jax-ws jars I need?

Answer (score 0):

We did this for a while with Axis 2 under WAS 6.1 without the Web Services Feature Pack. That is, we deployed Axis 2 jars in the web application's WEB-INF/lib. It did work, but had some performance and resource issues at the time. Thus, we decided to install the (free) Feature Pack, and that made everything work easier and better.

Also, though, don't forget that WebSphere 6.1 goes out of service this month.

As to the incompatible Java version from Java 1.5, JAX-WS can work with Java 1.5, but I have no idea whether your particular code needs Java 6.